# Linux Messenger program to communicate with Windows 7/8 MSG.exe utility

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8, samba, ipmsg

I have found out that NetSend has been taken out of Windows 7/8 and replaced with Msg.exe. This is great and all, but if I want to send a message from Linux with `smbclient` to Windows without the Windows user installing a 3rd party Lan Messenger, I can not do this without netsend,right?

SO how would I send a message from Linux distribution to Windows 8 with out installing any 3rd party software on Windows host?

Answer (score 1):

Might be just a stupid suggestion but you could try copying over the msg.exe and its dependencies and run it over wine.

I will try as soon as I get time.

I also found a project on Codeplex might try to compile the project in mono.

http://fastmessages.codeplex.com/

Not sure of anything in this project, might not be even what you need.

Comment: No it's not stupid actually. That might work

Comment: +1 The idea is nice. You will run into a couple of problems though. First the dependencies. `MSG.EXE` will give you a `LoadString failed, Error 1813` so you need to find all the dependencies (if at all possible). After that you might get a credential problem. I tried `msg /server:x` from `Win7->Win7` and i kept getting `Error 5 getting session names` (even after `AllowRemoteRPC=1`) I **needed** to add machine/user/password in the **"Windows Credentials"** to be able to send a message to that machine. `Wine` doesn't have the "Windows Credentials" (as far as i know).